# How to write a function that only accepts one enum variant as input?

Tags: function, enums, rust

I have an enum:

```rust
enum Group {
    OfTwo {
        first: usize,
        second: usize,
    },
    OfThree {
        one: usize,
        two: usize,
        three: usize,
    },
}
```

I would like to write a function that only takes as argument the `Group::OfTwo` variant:

```rust
fn proceed_pair(pair: Group::OfTwo) {}
```

But when I do that, I get the message:

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `Group::OfTwo`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:23
   |
13 | fn proceed_pair(pair: Group::OfTwo) {}
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       not a type
   |                       help: try using the variant's enum: `crate::Group`
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The variants of an `enum` are *values* and all have the same *type* - the `enum` itself. A function argument is a variable of a given type, and the function body must be valid for *any* value of that type. So what you want to do will just not work.

However, there is a common pattern for designing enums, which might help here. That is, to use a separate `struct` to hold the data for each `enum` variant. For example:

```
enum Group {
    OfTwo(OfTwo),
    OfThree(OfThree),
}

struct OfTwo { first: usize, second: usize }
struct OfThree { one: usize, two: usize, three: usize }

fn proceed_pair(pair: OfTwo) {

}
```

Anywhere that you previously matched on the `enum` like this:

```
match group {
    Group::OfTwo { first, second } => {}
    Group::OfThree { first, second, third } => {}
}
```

You would replace with:

```
match group {
    Group::OfTwo(OfTwo { first, second }) => {}
    Group::OfThree(OfThree { first, second, third }) => {}
}
```